# Renaming columns in data frame by excel file R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, rename

I have a data frame in R with several columns, e.g.
help1|help2|help3...
I have an excel file with the following columns:

- old_name new_name
- help1    help_org
- help2     help_fam
- help3     help_friend

I want R to go over the excel file, and rename the DF colnames according to the new_name column

help_org|help_fam|help_friend

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I understand, unfortunately I don't manage to put it in a list for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names(df) <- ref_df$new_name[match(names(df), ref_df$old_name)]
df
#     help_org   help_fam help_friend
#1 -0.56047565  1.7150650   1.2240818
#2 -0.23017749  0.4609162   0.3598138
#3  1.55870831 -1.2650612   0.4007715
#4  0.07050839 -0.6868529   0.1106827
#5  0.12928774 -0.4456620  -0.5558411
```

Where `ref_df` is data from excel file which has two columns (`old_name` and `new_name`).

```
ref_df <- readr::read_excel('excel_data.xlsx')
```

and `df` is your original data to change the column names.

For this example I used the data as :

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(help1 = rnorm(5), help2 = rnorm(5), help3 = rnorm(5))

ref_df <- structure(list(old_name = c("help1", "help2", "help3"), 
new_name = c("help_org", "help_fam", "help_friend")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```